# Convert an excel file into csv file in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I am downloading a XLS file by using shell script but unable to convert the .xls format to .csv format. I have tried xls2csv but its not working on my box. Is it possible by any other means to open the XLS file in shell or convert its format to .csv.

Comment: How did you use `xls2csv`? What arguments did you use? What errors did you see?

Comment: xls2csv -x XLSfile -c CSVfile. I don't know whether we can use this in unix because every time it says command not found...and i don't see any package to for this. thats why I ask any other means?

Comment: did you look around on how to install `xls2csv` in your system? You probably don't have it installed in the first place